# didSelectRowAtIndexPath only working on long press if embedded in container view

Tags: swift, touch, didselectrowatindexpath, uicontainerview

I'm creating a prototype for an app that uses the exact same UITableViewController class file for two different scenarios.

- The **first scenario** is for displaying a list of newly created "project" items. In this scenario I am using a regular Table View Controller in my StoryBoard.
- The **second scenario** allows the user to select from the existing "project" items in a different view. In this scenario I have a *regular* View Controller that has a **container view**. The container view uses an embedded tableview controller to display the selectable list.

To be clear, here is how my **second scenario** looks:

[image]

Remember, both are using the **exact** same class file. The **first scenario** works perfectly while the second scenario only calls `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` on a long press, taps don't work at all.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("fires") // scenario 2 does not fire until long press
    if selectable {
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) else { return }
        cell.accessoryType = (cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark) ? .None : .Checkmark
    }
}
```

### My Question

With my table view controller embedded in a **container view**, How can I get didSelectRowAtIndexPath to fire on a tap rather than a long press?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue which was caused by the container view not implementing touch methods and passing them up the chain with calls to super:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
```

I didn't have any touch functionality in the container, but still the calls needed to be made and passed up the chain in order for my table view to act on them.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where i would add this. Do I create a new class for my container view object? Or do I add it to my Table View Controller? I'm thinking the former.

Comment: Right - subclass your container view.

Comment: I've created a subclass of UIView and added it to my container view in interface builder. The touchesBegan function doesn't fire. I also tried just extending UIView and still no go.

Comment: Touch events have to be passed along the view hierarchy via super. If it is true that your container view is a subclass of UIView, just implement the touch handlers in your container view.
If your original container view is not a UIView or there are any other views between your table view and the top view (which receives your touch events) you need to refactor.
One way to se where touch events are getting lost is by starting to implement touch handlers from the top down and set breakpoints so that you can observe that your touches are being handled.